# ggplot2 geom_bar color only one column

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Consider a sample dataframe and the relative `geom_bar` plot

```
data = data.frame(method=LETTERS[sample(x=c(1,2,3),size=100,replace=T)], 
                  x1=sample(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),size=100,replace=T), 
                  x2=sample(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),size=100,replace=T),
                  d =letters[sample(c(1,2,3,4),size=100,replace=T)] )

ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data=data, aes(x=method, y=x1),stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~d, ncol=2)
```

I would like to color the smaller column of each plot of red.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would do it without collapsing your data to be able to create a new column which specifies which value is the minimum. Then you can attach an aesthetic to that value. Here's a collapsing strategy using your data

```
collapsed < -as.data.frame(xtabs(x1~d+method, data))
collapsed$ismin <- with(collapsed, ave(Freq,d,FUN=function(x) x==min(x)))
```

And now we plot with

```
ggplot(collapsed, aes(x=method, y=Freq, fill=as.factor(ismin)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~d, ncol=2) + 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("0","1"), values=c("black","red"), guide="none")
```

which results in

[image: bar char with min mbar colored red in each factet]